# Adding an If statement to my function

Tags: c++

Just began coding and have an assignment that prompts the user to enter "wage" and "hours" then calculate.  We're beginning to use functions and I wrote a code that calls the code, but I get an error saying my if statement in the function will never be executed.  Here's the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

float calcwage (float h, float w);

int main()
{
    float wage, hours, totwage;
    cout << setiosflags(ios::fixed|ios::showpoint)
    << setprecision(2);
    cout << "Enter hours worked: ";
    cin >> hours;
    cout << "Enter hourly wage:$ ";
    cin >> wage;
    totwage = calcwage (hours, wage);
    cout <<"Total wages=$ " << totwage << "\n";
    return 0;
}

float calcwage (float h, float w)
{
    return h * w; if(h <= 40)
        ;
    return (h * (w * 1.5)); if(h > 40)
        ;
}
```

Are if statements not allowed in functions? I'm confused and am not sure how my code can return back to main.

Comment: Do you know how if statements work in main?

Comment: So, you've invented your own syntax? [Read the manual.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if)

Comment: I believe you have to read up on c++ grammar. The grammar for if statements are `if ( <condition> ) <statement>;` **not** `<statement>; if ( <condition>;` http://www.cppforschool.com/tutorial/foc.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your if statements need to be before the return statements.

Also you only need on if statement since there are only two options. If the first one doesn't get hit than no need to check the other option as its the only other option.

if(h <=40) return h*w;

return h*w*1.5